# How to add a tab inside a column widget on flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My goal is to add a tab inside a colum, and add more widgets on this column.

But when i'm adding a tab, i'm getting an error of

> Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height. 
>       Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to 
>       match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an 
>       unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.
>       Any suggestions what i'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Here is my sample code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:trip_finder/screens/home_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Trip Finder',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xFF131415),
        primaryColorLight: Color(0xFF8296ab),
        highlightColor: Color(0xFF47bee1),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFFf0f1f1)
      ),
//      home: HomeScreen(),
      home: TestScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child:  Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _tabSection(),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

Widget _tabSection() {
  return DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: TabBar(tabs: [
            Tab(text: "Home"),
            Tab(text: "Articles"),
            Tab(text: "User"),
          ]),
        ),
        Container(
          child: TabBarView(children: [
            Container(
              child: Text("Home Body"),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text("Articles Body"),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text("User Body"),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I added `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,` to the `Container` that's the parent of `TabBarView` in your code, it worked, somehow.

Comment: thanks man, adding that property will fix the error

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can add height to your TabBarView. Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _tabSection(context),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

Widget _tabSection(BuildContext context) {
  return DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: TabBar(tabs: [
            Tab(text: "Home"),
            Tab(text: "Articles"),
            Tab(text: "User"),
          ]),
        ),
        Container( 
          //Add this to give height
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: TabBarView(children: [
            Container(
              child: Text("Home Body"),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text("Articles Body"),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text("User Body"),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also wrap inside `Flexible`.

```dart
Flexible(
    child: Container(
        child: TabBarView(
            children: [
                Container(
                    child: Text("Home Body"),
                ),
                Container(
                    child: Text("Articles Body"),
                ),
                Container(
                    child: Text("User Body"),
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

above TabBarView example proper but flutter 3.13.9 version

and height setting according to your requirement

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _tabSection(context),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

Widget _tabSection(BuildContext context) {
  return DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        const TabBar(tabs: [
          Tab(text: "Home"),
          Tab(text: "Articles"),
          Tab(text: "User"),
        ]),
        SizedBox(
          //Add this to give height
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.50,
          child: const TabBarView(children: [
            Text("Home Body"),
            Text("Articles Body"),
            Text("User Body"),
          ]),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: It's in a situation where we are getting dynamic data contents, we can't specify the height like that.