# Flutter scrollable TabBarView in Column without predefined size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to have a screen with a widget at the top followed by a TabBar. I want that everything is inside a SingleChildScrollView so that the whole screen can be scrolled (not only content of a single tab).

```
--------------------
|      Widget      |
--------------------
|      TabBar      |
--------------------
|                  |
|                  |
|    TabBarView    |
|                  |
|                  |
--------------------
```

I had a look at similar questions but they did not help with what I am trying to achieve:

[How to add a tab inside a column widget on flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58620053/how-to-add-a-tab-inside-a-column-widget-on-flutter)

[Make TabBarView take up all remaining space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995077/make-tabbarview-take-up-all-remaining-space)

I cannot set a fixed height as I don't know it (tab bar content).

My approach which is not working:

```
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Text('My Top Widget'),
              ),
              TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(child: Text('Available')),
                  Tab(child: Text('Taken')),
                ],
              ),
              TabBarView(
                children: [
                  Center(child: Text('1')),
                  Center(child: Text('2')),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.

Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  TabBarView file:///home/kay/Code/emat/frontend/lib/ui/TestScreen.dart:26:15
```

How it should be in the end:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: may be try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433885/sliverappbar-with-tabbar/50853287#50853287 @xooback

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I finally solved this issue. I had a look at how slivers work and chose to use them. I can suggest [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mz3kHQxBjGg&t=6s) as an introduction and the online docs for further reading.

Here is my approach now:

```
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
        body: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: NestedScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
              SliverToBoxAdapter( //headerSilverBuilder only accepts slivers
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: Text('My Top Widget'),
                    ),
                    TabBar(
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(child: Text('Available')),
                        Tab(child: Text('Taken')),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                // I wrapped large widgets in the SingleChildScrollView
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Text('1')/*Very large widget*/,
                ),
                Text('2'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But this makes the top widget go up to the top of the screen and eventually disappear even if there is little to no data in TabBarViews.

Comment: Could be that this solution is outdated by now. I haven't touched flutter in a while and cannot guarantee that this solution is still valid...