# TabBarView within Scrollable Page

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, flutter-layout, overflow

I am having real trouble getting a layout to work within Flutter.

**The layout I am trying to create:**

- A `ListView` that contains a:

  - A `Container`.
  - A `TabBar`.
  - A `TabBarView`, where each `TabBarView` contains a `Column`.
- And I want the **whole page** to be scrollable.

Here is the schematic for the layout:

[image]

**Example Code**

Here is a minimum example code (with exact widget definitions removed):

```dart
return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          // TOP CONTAINER //
          Container(height: 30),

          // TAB BAR //

          const TabBar(tabs: [
            Tab(child: Text("Tab 1")),
            Tab(child: Text("Tab 2")),
          ]),

          // TAB BAR VIEWS //
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: TabBarView(
              children: [
                Container(height: 5000),
                Container(height: 5000),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

**The Problem**:

When the height of the window gets smaller, I get an overflow error at the bottom:

**What I have Done**:

- I first tried converting the inner `Column` into a `ListView`, which fixed the overflow, but resulted in two separate scrollable areas (the individual tab views and the whole page), which is not what I want - I want a single scrollable area. Setting the `physics` property of this `ListView` to `NeverScrollablePhysics()` doesnt fix this and results in some weird behaviour.
- I tried using a `NestedScrollView` with `Silvers` (from [How to create a bounded scrollable TabBarView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747149/how-to-create-a-bounded-scrollable-tabbarview)). But this results in the following exception when navigating through the tabs: `The provided ScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition.`, and produces some dodgy scroll mechanics.
- I tried using a `CustomScrollView`  but that didnt work.

**Similar Questions that Didnt provide a working solution:**

- [Flutter scrollable TabBarView in Column without predefined size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397897/flutter-scrollable-tabbarview-in-column-without-predefined-size)
- [How to create a bounded scrollable TabBarView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747149/how-to-create-a-bounded-scrollable-tabbarview)
- [how to implement a sliverAppBar with a tabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741732/how-to-implement-a-sliverappbar-with-a-tabbar)
- [Getting 'Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.' with TabBarView in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023610/getting-horizontal-viewport-was-given-unbounded-height-with-tabbarview-in-flu)

I am very confused as to why it is not working as I feel this is a very simple thing. Essentially, it is the same layout used in the Instragram app (among others) when viewing your personal profile (see: https://unblast.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Instagram-UI-Profile-1.jpg).

Comment: Wrap the SingleChildScrollView with ``Expanded``

Comment: @pasha i am not using a SingleChildScrollView - where should I place it?

Comment: Expanded-> SingleChildScrollView -> ListView( make shrinkWrap: true and physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() for ListView)

Comment: No that hasnt done it - I get an error when using the Expanded widget and the SingleChildScrollView gives me two scrollable areas still.

Comment: @pasha would you be able to produce a code example for it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71769800/implement-tabbar-under-appbar/71769862?noredirect=1#comment126833382_71769862

i just answered this here it is very similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments you can wrap your page in a `singlechildscrollview`, disable scroll physics for the listview as the parent is already scrollable.

```
return SIngleChildScrollView(child: DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: ListView(
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          // TOP CONTAINER //
          Container(height: 30),

          // TAB BAR //

          const TabBar(tabs: [
            Tab(child: Text("Tab 1")),
            Tab(child: Text("Tab 2")),
          ]),

          // TAB BAR VIEWS //
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: TabBarView(
              children: [
                Container(height: 5000),
                Container(height: 5000),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
```

** Option2 **

you can use a `customScrollView` or a `nestedScrollView`

```
DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child:
CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [

SlivertoboxAdapter(child:   // TOP CONTAINER //
          Container(height: 30),

SlivertoboxAdapter(child:   // TAB BAR //

          const TabBar(tabs: [
            Tab(child: Text("Tab 1")),
            Tab(child: Text("Tab 2")),
          ]),

//... Sliverfillremaining/slivettoboxadapter for your tabbarview

SlivertoboxAdapter(child:TabBarView(
              children: [
                Container(height: 5000),
                Container(height: 5000),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: sorry Im on mobile ,I'll fomart the answer once on a desktop

Comment: Yeah using `NestedScrollView` kind of works but it produces an exception (`The provided ScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition`).

Comment: also @griffins - this works but it produces two scroll areas - the scroll area for the `NestedScrollView` or `CustomScrollView` and the scroll area for the `ListView` that I have in `TabView`.

Comment: let the parent widget be the only scrollable widget set physcis on other scrollable  components and remove the scroll controller from them i.e `physics:NeverScrollablePhysics(),`

Comment: what about tabbarview inside has listview ?

Answer (score 2):

I have scratched my head around `TabBarView` many times with a question 'How to put dynamic-height content inside `TabBarView` while it is inside a scrollable container?'

Unfortunately, it is broken for such use cases as the scroll and does not work correctly and the content overflows.

Hence, my solution answers the OP question by answering how to achieve the whole page scrollable. It replaces `TabBarView` with different mechanism.

My solution is to skip `TabBarView` and use `TabBar` and `TabController` to get a `Widget` from the `Widget` list.

Code:

```dart
// STATEFUL WIDGET CODE

late TabController tabController; // USED FOR NAVIGATION

@override
void initState() {
    tabController = TabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 3, // adjust your length
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
               appBar: // some app bar
               body: SingleChildScrollView(
                    Column(
                        children: [
                            TabBar(controller: tabController),
                            _getTabAtIndex(tabContoller.index),
                        ]
                    )
                )

    );
}

Widget _getTabAtIndex(int index) {
   var list = [
     Container(), // FIRST ITEM
     Container(), // SECOND ITEM
     Container(), // THIRD ITEM
   ];
   return list[index];
}
```